# Mono packaged version with debain stable version

Tags: linux, mono, debian-jessie

I have installed debian stable version and it is packaged default with mono 3.2.8 version. However I see mono 3.2.8 is from 3 years back and the latest stable version is 5.0.1.1 in the mono [release list](http://list.http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/)

Here is the link where it shows packaged version of mono with debian
https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=mono-runtime&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

1) I want to know why stable version of debian points to very outdated mono version? Is there any reason for not updating default mono version to latest one's 4.8 or higher?

Comment: I think the next debian stable (which is just around the corner) will include what UbuntuLTS nowadays includes: mono 4.2.1

Comment: Debian 9 Stretch → **mono 4.6.2.7** https://packages.debian.org/stretch/mono-complete

Answer (score 1):

Debian stable is not "stable versions of software," it's a stable operating system. Stable in this context doesn't mean "it doesn't crash," it means that the packages in it doesn't change. [Here's the official description of the releases](https://www.debian.org/releases/).

The reason why debian stable points to an outdated version of pretty much everything is that it takes a long time for a version of a package to get into stable. If you want modern versions of things, I suggest running unstable or testing.